# Lightbox 2 - more than one gallery on a one-pager

Tags: lightbox2

I wanted to know, how I can use more than one light boxes from Lightbox2 on a one-pager.
It works but its all in one Gallery.
How can I divide that galleries to be separated in a Lightbox?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following within the html:

Initial symbol deleted at beginning to get it to get it to display!
a href="photos_2021/photo1.jpg" data-lightbox="member" data-title="Text to display">
.... and again!
img src="photos_2021/photo1.jpg" alt="Text to display"/>

As an aside, Note that the thumbnail photo is the same as the actual photo to be displayed - saves on having to produce 2 versions.

The word "member" defines which group of photos it is part of so you can add "member2","member3" etc. for different groups of photos within the same page.

Comment: and how do I use it in Javascript?